# gevent - 'module' object has no attribute 'epoll' with Python2-7 and Gevent -1.0.x; with Requests-2.x.x

Tags: python, request, gevent

has anyone used Gevent -1.0.1; with Requests-2.9.1? I am getting the following error (AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'epoll') I believe this started happening only recently.

Also, if I use patch_all(select=False), then this error goes away, but also, concurrency doesn’t happen.

Here is the code:

```
./greenlet_eg.py
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import functools

from gevent.pool import Pool
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()   # This must be called before any other modules calling socket/request

from common import ApiClient, work_function, URLS

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def main():
    t1 = datetime.now()
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.NOTSET, format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(process)d/%(thread)d: %(message)s")
    no_of_jobs,no_of_workers = 1000,100
    log.info('Starting script for # of jobs: {} running # of workers at a time {}...'.format(no_of_jobs, no_of_workers))
    api_client = ApiClient(no_of_jobs)
    pool = Pool(no_of_workers)
    work_function_with_one_arg =  functools.partial(work_function, api_client)
    results = pool.map(work_function_with_one_arg, api_client.max_urls)
    log.info(datetime.now() - t1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


./common.py

import requests
import time
import random
import os
import threading
from datetime import datetime
import functools
import logging
import subprocess

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

URLS = [
    'http://www.python.org', 
    'http://www.python.org/about/',
    'http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2003/04/17/metaclasses.html',
    'http://www.python.org/doc/',
    'http://www.python.org/download/',
    'http://www.python.org/getit/',
    'http://www.python.org/community/',
    'https://wiki.python.org/moin/',
    'http://planet.python.org/',
    'https://wiki.python.org/moin/LocalUserGroups',
    'http://www.python.org/psf/',
    'http://docs.python.org/devguide/',
    'http://www.python.org/community/awards/'
]

class ApiClient():
    def __init__(self, no_of_jobs):
        self.max_urls = [URLS[random.randint(0,len(URLS)-1)]+str(i) for i in range(no_of_jobs)]

    def get_content(self, url):
        try:
            return requests.get(url).content
        except:
            logging.exception('Error while getting url {}'.format(url))
            return None

def work_function(api_client, url):
    log.info('Parsing {}.. PID: {}, threadid: {}'.format(url, os.getpid(), threading.currentThread().ident))
    return api_client.get_content(url)

def main():
    t1 = datetime.now()
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.NOTSET, format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(process)d/%(thread)d: %(message)s")
    no_of_jobs,no_of_workers = 1000,100
    log.info('Starting script for # of jobs: {} running # of workers at a time {}...'.format(no_of_jobs, no_of_workers))
    api_client = ApiClient(no_of_jobs)
    results = []
    work_function_with_one_arg =  functools.partial(work_function, api_client=api_client)
    for url in api_client.max_urls:
        results.append(work_function_with_one_arg(url=url))
    log.info(datetime.now() - t1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the Error: …

```
2017-05-23 16:53:41,501 ERROR root 7757/140199531697968: Error while getting url http://planet.python.org/993
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/src/NetengCommon/examples/concurrency_vs_threading_vs_multiprocessing/common.py", line 35, in get_content
    return requests.get(url).content
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 190, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 324, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 438, in wrap_socket
    rd = util.wait_for_read(sock, sock.gettimeout())
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/wait.py", line 33, in wait_for_read
    return _wait_for_io_events(socks, EVENT_READ, timeout)
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/wait.py", line 22, in _wait_for_io_events
    with DefaultSelector() as selector:
  File "/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Requests/Requests-2.x.x.2946.2/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/selectors.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._epoll = select.epoll()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'epoll'
2017-05-23 16:53:41,503 INFO __main__ 7757/140199633593040: 0:00:08.594773
```

To make the code very simple...

requests 2.13.0 fails

```
>>> import sys
>>> import gevent.monkey
>>> gevent.monkey.patch_all()   # This must be called before any other modules calling socket/request
>>> import requests
>>>
>>> print 'py version:', sys.version_info
py version: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> print 'requests version:', requests.__version__
requests version: 2.13.0
>>> print 'gevent version:', gevent.__version__
gevent version: 1.0.1
>>>
>>> assert requests.get('http://www.python.org').content

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 190, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 324, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 438, in wrap_socket
    rd = util.wait_for_read(sock, sock.gettimeout())
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/wait.py", line 33, in wait_for_read
    return _wait_for_io_events(socks, EVENT_READ, timeout)
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/wait.py", line 22, in _wait_for_io_events
    with DefaultSelector() as selector:
  File "/home/barikak/workplace/NetengCommonW/env/NetengCommon-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/selectors.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._epoll = select.epoll()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'epoll'
>>>
>>>
```

requests 2.9.1 works

```
>>> import sys
>>> import gevent.monkey
>>> gevent.monkey.patch_all()   # This must be called before any other modules calling socket/request
>>>
>>> import requests
>>>
>>> print 'py version:', sys.version_info
py version: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> print 'requests version:', requests.__version__
requests version: 2.9.1
>>> print 'gevent version:', gevent.__version__
gevent version: 1.0.1
>>>
>>> assert requests.get('http://www.python.org').content
/home/barikak/workplace/NSDSwiftKanbanClientW/env/NSDSwiftKanbanClient-1.0/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
>>>
```